# Xamarin Forms Geocoder: no compilation or runtime errors, and no results

Tags: google-maps, f#, xamarin.forms, geocoding

I've been building a Xamarin Forms-based app with mapping enabled, using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) guide. The map is working without any problems; however, the geocoding functionality is failing silently.

My View contains a `SearchBox`, which is wired up to a command that uses a Xamarin Forms `Geocoder` instance to find user-defined addresses. The command is firing correctly when an address is entered into the `SearchBox`:

[image: SearchBox Demo]

However, while I'm debugging, the Geocoder returns instantly, coming back with no results at all. The action happens in the `geocodeAddress` function below:

```
type DashboardViewModel(?host: IScreen, ?platform: IPlatform) as this =
    inherit ReactiveViewModel()
    let host, platform = LocateIfNone host, LocateIfNone platform
    let searchResults = new ObservableCollection<GeodesicLocation>()
    let geocodeAddress(vm: DashboardViewModel) =
        let vm = match box vm with | null -> this | _ -> vm
        searchResults.Clear()
        async {
            let! results = platform.Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(vm.SearchAddress) |> Async.AwaitTask
            results |> Seq.map (fun r -> new GeodesicLocation(r.Latitude * 1.0<deg>, r.Longitude * 1.0<deg>)) |> Seq.iter searchResults.Add
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
    let searchForAddress = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask geocodeAddress
    let mutable location = new GeodesicLocation()
    let mutable searchAddress = String.Empty
    member __.Title with get() = LocalisedStrings.AppTitle
    member __.SearchForAddress with get() = searchForAddress
    member this.SearchAddress with get() = searchAddress and set(value) = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&searchAddress, value, "SearchAddress") |> ignore
    member this.LatitudeDegrees 
        with get() = location.Latitude / 1.0<deg> 
        and set(value) = location <- new GeodesicLocation(value * 1.0<deg>, location.Longitude); this.RaisePropertyChanged("LatitudeDegrees")
    member this.LongitudeDegrees 
        with get() = location.Longitude / 1.0<deg> 
        and set(value) = location <- new GeodesicLocation(location.Latitude, value * 1.0<deg>); this.RaisePropertyChanged("LongitudeDegrees")
    interface IRoutableViewModel with
        member __.HostScreen = host
        member __.UrlPathSegment = "Dashboard"
```

According to the Xamarin [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/geocoder/geocode_an_address/), the `Geocoder` class should work out of the box. Am I missing some kind of setup?

**UPDATE**: The code for the View is as follows. This isn't built with XAML, but it's an F#-based structure that is reasonably similar to XAML.

```
type DashboardView(theme: Theme) as this = 
    inherit ContentPage<DashboardViewModel, DashboardView>(theme)
    new() = new DashboardView(Themes.AstridTheme)
    override __.CreateContent() =
        theme.GenerateGrid([|"Auto"; "*"|], [|"*"|]) |> withColumn(
            [|
                theme.VerticalLayout() |> withBlocks(
                    [|
                        theme.GenerateLabel(fun l -> this.Title <- l) 
                            |> withAlignment LayoutOptions.Center LayoutOptions.Center
                            |> withOneWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.Title @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.Title: Label).Text @>)
                        theme.GenerateSearchBar(fun sb -> this.AddressSearchBar <- sb)
                            |> withSearchBarPlaceholder LocalisedStrings.SearchForAPlaceOfInterest
                            |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.SearchAddress @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.AddressSearchBar: SearchBar).Text @>)
                            |> withSearchCommand this.ViewModel.SearchForAddress
                    |])
                theme.GenerateMap(new GeodesicLocation(51.4<deg>, 0.0<deg>), 4.0<km>, fun m -> this.Map <- m)
                    |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.LatitudeDegrees @>, <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.Map: Map).VisibleRegion.LatitudeDegrees @>)
                    |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.LongitudeDegrees @>, <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.Map: Map).VisibleRegion.LongitudeDegrees @>)
            |]) |> createFromColumns :> View
    member val AddressSearchBar = Unchecked.defaultof<SearchBar> with get, set
    member val Title = Unchecked.defaultof<Label> with get, set
    member val Map = Unchecked.defaultof<Map> with get, set
```

Comment: Can you show the xaml?

Comment: I'll edit the question to show you the View (not built with XAML).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an issue with the Visual Studio emulator. When I run the debugger on my device via a USB, it has no problem finding the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, I suspect the issue is that you need to make a public property for the `searchResults`, and bind it from the map:

```
member this.SearchResults with get() = searchResults
```

This would allow you to bind the search results.

You also will likely need to switch to the UI threading context before adding to `searchResults` within the async workflow.  Adding to an `ObservableCollection<'T>` in a background thread typically results in nothing being rendered, or a crash.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't get as far as this. The `results` collection is always empty. I'm using ReactiveUI, so I should probably do something sophisticated like use a `ReactiveCollection` and observe it on the UI thread. The trouble is, if I don't find any results, there will be nothing for the UI thread to do.